# How to calculate the relation between 2 lists of boolean/binary (true/false or 1/0) values?

Tags: correlation, binary-data

We have performed analyses on REST API endpoints to detect if they violate REST linguistic principles (i.e. if the URIs are well designed) or if they violate other REST design principles (for example using non-standard headers, not correctly implementing/using for example caching, mime-types, status codes).

So we have 2 categories of anti-patterns, we call these categories linguistic anti-patterns and design anti-patterns. For each analyzed API endpoint, we have registered if it has any of these anti-patterns (true) or not (false).

We have multiple different representations of this, one is [this txt file](https://github.com/rest-api-antipattern-inspector/antipattern-correlations/blob/master/correlation-data/results.txt) where the name of each anti-pattern is listed followed by a line of numbers, either 1 or 0. Each number represents an API endpoint, 1 means that the endpoint has that anti-pattern, 0 means that it does not. Each line of numbers has the same length, same amount of numbers, a number (1/0) for each endpoint.

We now want to calculate the relation/correlation between the occurrences of these anti-patterns (particularly between linguistic and design anti-patterns, and vice-versa), how should we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [a source](https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365) on this topic of correlation relating to dummy variables:

> A popular approach for dichotomous variables (i.e. variables with only two categories) is built on the chi-squared distribution. We are not interested in testing the statistical significance however, we are more interested in effect size and specifically in the strength of association between the two variables. Thankfully, several coefficients have been defined for this purpose, including several which use the chi-square statistic. Here are some examples:
>
> 1. [Goodman Kruskal’s lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_lambda)
> 2. [Phi co-efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) (uses chi-squared statistic)
> 3. [Cramer’s V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) (uses chi-squared statistic)
> 4. [Tschuprow’s T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschuprow%27s_T) (uses chi-squared statistic)
> 5. [Contingency coefficient C](https://www.statisticshowto.com/contingency-coefficient/) (uses chi-squared statistic)

I recommend the Phi coefficient based on a consistency argument, as it equates to the Pearson correlation coefficient estimated on two binary variables.